# Bootstrap Image Gallery with MixItUp Filtering

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, image-gallery, mixitup

I'm using the **Bootstrap Image Gallery** plugin together with **MixItUp** filtering.
The image gallery contains over 150 images and I want if a thumbnail of a selected filter is clicked to cycle only through the images for that selected filter and not all the images in the gallery.
I tried to create a div for each filter but it's not working.
Probably each filter wrapped in a div together with some javascript could work, but I don't know how.
Here the HTML & JS of a stripped down sample and the **[LINK](http://benjapakee.atspace.com/Sample/index.html)** to see it online:

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<title>Gallery Sample</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<!-- Gallery Section -->

<section id="gallery" class="bg-light-gray">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <h2 class="section-heading">Gallery</h2>
    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted"></h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="controls">
  <ul class="portfolio-filter">
    <li class="btn btn-primary active margin-5 filter" data-filter="all">All</li>
    <li class="btn btn-primary margin-5 filter" data-filter=".nangphaya">Nang Phaya</li>
    <li class="btn btn-primary margin-5 filter" data-filter=".phrarod">Phra Rod</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid galleries"> 
  <!-- Gallery Nang Phaya -->
  <div class="mix nangphaya col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/nangphaya/nangphaya001.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/nangphaya/thumb/nangphaya001.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix nangphaya col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/nangphaya/nangphaya002.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/nangphaya/thumb/nangphaya002.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix nangphaya col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/nangphaya/nangphaya003.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/nangphaya/thumb/nangphaya003.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix nangphaya col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/nangphaya/nangphaya004.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/nangphaya/thumb/nangphaya004.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix nangphaya col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/nangphaya/nangphaya005.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/nangphaya/thumb/nangphaya005.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix nangphaya col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/nangphaya/nangphaya006.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/nangphaya/thumb/nangphaya006.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix nangphaya col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/nangphaya/nangphaya007.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/nangphaya/thumb/nangphaya007.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix nangphaya col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/nangphaya/nangphaya008.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/nangphaya/thumb/nangphaya008.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix nangphaya col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/nangphaya/nangphaya009.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/nangphaya/thumb/nangphaya009.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix nangphaya col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/nangphaya/nangphaya010.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/nangphaya/thumb/nangphaya010.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix nangphaya col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/nangphaya/nangphaya011.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/nangphaya/thumb/nangphaya011.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix nangphaya col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/nangphaya/nangphaya012.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/nangphaya/thumb/nangphaya012.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <!-- Gallery Phra Rod -->
  <div class="mix phrarod col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/phrarod/phrarod001.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/phrarod/thumb/phrarod001.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix phrarod col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/phrarod/phrarod002.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/phrarod/thumb/phrarod002.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix phrarod col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/phrarod/phrarod003.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/phrarod/thumb/phrarod003.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix phrarod col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/phrarod/phrarod004.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/phrarod/thumb/phrarod004.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix phrarod col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/phrarod/phrarod005.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/phrarod/thumb/phrarod005.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix phrarod col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/phrarod/phrarod006.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/phrarod/thumb/phrarod006.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix phrarod col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/phrarod/phrarod007.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/phrarod/thumb/phrarod007.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix phrarod col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/phrarod/phrarod008.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/phrarod/thumb/phrarod008.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix phrarod col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/phrarod/phrarod009.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/phrarod/thumb/phrarod009.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix phrarod col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/phrarod/phrarod010.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/phrarod/thumb/phrarod010.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix phrarod col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/phrarod/phrarod011.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/phrarod/thumb/phrarod011.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
  <div class="mix phrarod col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <a href="img/gallery/phrarod/phrarod012.jpg" data-gallery title=""> <img src="img/gallery/phrarod/thumb/phrarod012.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery" data-use-bootstrap-modal="false"> 
  <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
  <div class="slides"></div>
  <!-- Controls for the borderless lightbox --> 
  <a class="prev">‹</a> <a class="next">›</a> <a class="close">×</a> <a class="play-pause"></a>
  <ol class="indicator">
  </ol>
  <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
  <div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body next"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i> Previous </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next"> Next <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>

<!-- jQuery --> 
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Plugin JavaScript --> 
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Custom JavaScript --> 
<script src="js/custom.js"></script> 

<!-- Gallery JavaScript --> 
<script src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Scrollbar JavaScript --> 
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/nicescroll.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
// MixItUp
$(function(){
  $('.galleries').mixItUp({
    load: {
    }
  });
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated,